# How does Kubernetes' scheduler work?

Tags: kubernetes

How does Kubernetes' scheduler work? What I mean is that Kubernetes' scheduler appears to be very simple?

My initial thought is that this scheduler is just a simple admission control system, not a real scheduler. Is it that correct?

I found a short description, but it is not terribly informative:

> The kubernetes scheduler is a policy-rich, topology-aware,
>   workload-specific function that significantly impacts availability,
>   performance, and capacity. The scheduler needs to take into account
>   individual and collective resource requirements, quality of service
>   requirements, hardware/software/policy constraints, affinity and
>   anti-affinity specifications, data locality, inter-workload
>   interference, deadlines, and so on. Workload-specific requirements
>   will be exposed through the API as necessary.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The paragraph you quoted describes where we hope to be in the future (where the future is defined in units of months, not years). We're not there yet, but the scheduler does have a number of useful features already, enough for a simple deployment. In the rest of this reply, I'll explain how the scheduler works today.

The scheduler is not just an admission controller; for each pod that is created, it finds the "best" machine for that pod, and if no machine is suitable, the pod remains unscheduled until a machine becomes suitable.

The scheduler is configurable. It has two types of policies, **FitPredicate** (see `master/pkg/scheduler/predicates.go`) and **PriorityFunction** (see `master/pkg/scheduler/priorities.go`). I'll describe them.

**Fit predicates** are required rules, for example the labels on the node must be compatible with the label selector on the pod (this rule is implemented in `PodSelectorMatches()` in `predicates.go`), and the sum of the requested resources of the container(s) already running on the machine plus the requested resources of the new container(s) you are considering scheduling onto the machine must not be greater than the capacity of the machine (this rule is implemented in `PodFitsResources()` in `predicates.go`; note that "requested resources" is defined as *pod.Spec.Containers[n].Resources.Limits*, and if you request zero resources then you always fit). If any of the required rules are not satisfied for a particular (new pod, machine) pair, then the new pod is not scheduled on that machine. If after checking all machines the scheduler decides that the new pod cannot be scheduled onto any machine, then the pod remains in Pending state until it can be satisfied by one of the machines.

After checking all of the machines with respect to the fit predicates, the scheduler may find that multiple machines "fit" the pod. But of course, the pod can only be scheduled onto one machine. That's where priority functions come in. Basically, the scheduler ranks the machines that meet all of the fit predicates, and then chooses the best one. For example, it prefers the machine whose already-running pods consume the least resources (this is implemented in `LeastRequestedPriority()` in `priorities.go`). This policy spreads pods (and thus containers) out instead of packing lots onto one machine while leaving others empty.

When I said that the scheduler is configurable, I mean that you can decide at compile time which fit predicates and priority functions you want Kubernetes to apply. Currently, it applies all of the ones you see in `predicates.go` and `priorities.go`.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the old doc. Kuber use `request` to do scheduling and `limit` for resource restriction.

Comment: @DavidO Is there public documentation that describes the default Fit Predicates and Priority functions that are in place, in plain english instead of code? It would be helpful in order to explain to non-kubernites and make design decisions.

Comment: So two years later did you reach the intended goal you mention at the beginning of your answer?

Comment: Here is the design document for the scheudler https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/scheduler.md and here is the algorithm of default scheduler https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/scheduler_algorithm.md

Comment: The links are now https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-scheduling/scheduler.md and https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-scheduling/scheduler_algorithm.md

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh your first link is broken, and it appears is no `scheduler.md` file in that repo. The algorithm link works fine, though.

Comment: @AndrewRalon looks like https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-scheduling/scheduling_code_hierarchy_overview.md is the new one

Answer (score 7):

We've done customizations that, for example, apply multilevel affinity and anti affinity based on custom selectors.  The scheduler isn't perfect, but it's pretty good for most service level workloads, and in the future should get a lot better.  https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/scheduler.html#use-cases describes one particular Kube scheduler config that provides that.

Comment: Great detailed resource on the k8s scheduler!  Thanks for the link to OpenShift docs!

Comment: Hi, the link is broken. Could you fix that?

Comment: @xudifsd here is the link to the latest docs https://docs.okd.io/latest/admin_guide/scheduling/scheduler.html

Comment: Here is the latest docs as of today - https://docs.okd.io/latest/nodes/scheduling/nodes-scheduler-about.html

Answer (score 1):

The scheduler has a process set in place for it to pick a pod and place it in the right node and start it.

1. The user starts a new pod.
2. **Scheduler Queue:** This is the *[QueueSort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/scheduling-framework/#queue-sort)* phase. Pod is added to the scheduling queue. Based on the priority given to the pod it starts to schedule the pod [PriorityClasses](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/pod-priority-preemption/).
3. **Filtering:** This is the *[Filter](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/scheduling-framework/#filter)* phase. In this phase nodes that cannot schedule the pod are filtered based on resource limits, taints & tolerations, etc.
4. **Scoring:** This is the *[Score](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/scheduling-framework/#scoring)* phase. In this phase, the scheduler scores the nodes filtered based on the free space available before and after scheduling and then assigns a score. The node with the highest score is taken.
5. **Binding:** This is the *[Bind](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/scheduling-framework/#scoring)* phase. In this phase, the pod is bound to the node with the highest score and now the pod is finally scheduled.

**Advanced:** We also have *scheduling plugins* which we can add to each phase. Along with pre and post-actions (Eg: PreFilter, PostFilter, PreScore, etc) for each phase where you can bind plugins. Read more about it [scheduling framework](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/scheduling-framework/)

This is a short walk-through of the Kubernetes scheduler process. Hope it was helpful.