# Where the node capabilities are stored in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, scheduling, linux-capabilities

My questions related to kubernetes resource management:

1. How Kubernetes master collects all his nodes resource capabilities and then use those capabilities to schedule Pods as per there requirement and resource availability?.
2. Where the capabilities retrived from node are maintained in master node?(any database or go structure to mentain the data?).

Please suggest the file inside all this operations are performed.
I found the file location https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/plugin/pkg/scheduler/schedulercache/node_info.go , but did not found any code doing this operations.

3. How scheduler use resource information managed in master node for scheduling Pod?.

Answer (score 1):

1.
Here is detailed expiation how scheduler works. [How does Kubernetes' scheduler work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857993/how-does-kubernetes-scheduler-work?rq=1)

2. kubernetes uses etcd database to store the information.
3. This link the  information about scheduling. https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/scheduler.html#generic-scheduler

Comment: @sfggroups thanks for the above link, it is very useful to customize scheduler. My concern is how node capabilities taken from node to kubernetes master. I want to add some more capabilities feature to retrieve with node capabilities.